# In Netbeans 6.8 cant find org.netbeans package

Tags: plugins, java-me, netbeans6.8

I have netbeans 6.8 with java ME platform setup on my ubuntu 9.10.
My code requires the package **org.netbeans.microedition.lcdui** which is either not installed or not in the path. 
Surprising this runs perfectly in netbeans 6.8 on windows on my friend's pc.
Is there any java ME plugin I need to install?
Can somebody help me out with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like `netbeans_midp_components_basic.jar` is missing from your NB install for some reason.

Try get netbeans_midp_components_basic.jar off your friend's PC (under `[NetBeansRoot]/mobility8/modules/ext`) and put it in your own install in the same path. Or add it to your project's build path.

If the file `netbeans_midp_components_basic.jar` is missing, some others might be missing too which will cause problems down the line.  So a better way I'd suggest a reinstall, double checking that you get the NB6.8 that's bundled with the mobility pack.